# Style: real and imaginary part over same denominator?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

Sorry for the straightforward question but you're all the best people for me to ask.

My question is about style and best shown with an example.

Consider:

$$\frac{3-5i}{1+3i}$$

Is it acceptable to write the answer as:

$$\frac{-6-7i}{5}$$

Or must real and imaginary parts always be stated separately:

$$-\frac{6}{5} - \frac{7i}{5}$$

Or indeed should the $i$ be separate too?

$$-\frac{6}{5}-\frac{7}{5}i $$

Thanks.

Comment: If you are wishing to emphasize the $z = a+bi$ nature of a complex number, I would write it as the final variant however they are all acceptable including the original expression (*though the original is harder to use for most arithmetic purposes*).

Comment: In the intermediate steps, choose the most convenient algebraic form, but for the final answer, the expected form is $a + bi$, so your last answer is the preferred final form.

Comment: You could also write it as $-1.2 - i\,1.4$ or even $\sqrt{\frac{17}{5}}\left(-\frac{6}{\sqrt{85}}- i \, \frac{7}{\sqrt{85}}\right)\,$. There is no single one *best* form, that depends on the context.

Comment: Thank you all. Insightful, reassuring and helpful.